# gcc.exe fail when building cloudflare-zlib-sys.rs

Tags: gcc, rust, zlib, mingw-w64, amethyst

I am trying to install `sheep_cli` for `Amethyst.rs` game engine.
I have `x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0` MinGW installed. Maybe target is wrong?

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `cloudflare-zlib-sys v0.2.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installMN5vHV\release\build\cloudflare-zlib-sys-eda63c9230465ae7\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
--- stdout
OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
CC_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
CC_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
HOST_CC = None
CC = None
CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
HOST_CFLAGS = None
CFLAGS = None
CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
DEBUG = Some("false")
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
cargo:include=C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cloudflare-zlib-sys-0.2.0\vendor
CC_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
CC_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
HOST_CC = None
CC = None
CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
HOST_CFLAGS = None
CFLAGS = None
CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
CC_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
CC_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
HOST_CC = None
CC = None
CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
HOST_CFLAGS = None
CFLAGS = None
CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
running: "gcc.exe" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "C:\\Users\\user\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\cloudflare-zlib-sys-0.2.0\\vendor" "-mpclmul" "-msse4.2" "-msse4.2" "-DHAVE_OFF64_T=1" "-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=
1" "-DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1" "-DHAS_PCLMUL" "-DHAS_SSE42" "-DHAVE_HIDDEN=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installMN5vHV\\release\\build\\cloudflare-zlib-sys-399f3ab9f80722f4\\out\\crc32-pclmul_asm.o" "-c" "C:\\Users\\user\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\gith
ub.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\cloudflare-zlib-sys-0.2.0\\vendor\\contrib/amd64/crc32-pclmul_asm.S"
cargo:warning=C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cloudflare-zlib-sys-0.2.0\vendor\contrib/amd64/crc32-pclmul_asm.S: Assembler messages:
cargo:warning=C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cloudflare-zlib-sys-0.2.0\vendor\contrib/amd64/crc32-pclmul_asm.S:125: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.hidden'
cargo:warning=C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cloudflare-zlib-sys-0.2.0\vendor\contrib/amd64/crc32-pclmul_asm.S:125: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef: ignored.
cargo:warning=C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cloudflare-zlib-sys-0.2.0\vendor\contrib/amd64/crc32-pclmul_asm.S:125: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `c'
cargo:warning=C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cloudflare-zlib-sys-0.2.0\vendor\contrib/amd64/crc32-pclmul_asm.S:266: Warning: .size pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef: ignored.
cargo:warning=C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cloudflare-zlib-sys-0.2.0\vendor\contrib/amd64/crc32-pclmul_asm.S:266: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `c'
exit code: 1

--- stderr


error occurred: Command "gcc.exe" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-I" "C:\\Users\\user\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\cloudflare-zlib-sys-0.2.0\\vendor" "-mpclmul" "-msse4.2" "-msse4.2" "-DHAVE_OFF64_T=1" "-D_LARG
EFILE64_SOURCE=1" "-DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1" "-DHAS_PCLMUL" "-DHAS_SSE42" "-DHAVE_HIDDEN=1" "-o" "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installMN5vHV\\release\\build\\cloudflare-zlib-sys-399f3ab9f80722f4\\out\\crc32-pclmul_asm.o" "-c" "C:\\Users\\user\\.cargo\\regi
stry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\cloudflare-zlib-sys-0.2.0\\vendor\\contrib/amd64/crc32-pclmul_asm.S" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).



warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `sheep_cli v0.3.0`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installMN5vHV`

Caused by:
  build failed
```

Comment: Problem solved with linux migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That crate has the build problem you showed when it is built by the Rust MinGW toolchain, but it compiles fine if you use the MSVC toolchain, which requires the [Visual Studio C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) (or a recent version of Visual Studio).

To install the latest stable MSVC toolchain, use the following command:

```sh
rustup toolchain install stable-msvc
```

Then, to set it as the default toolchain for all your Rust projects:

```sh
rustup default stable-msvc
```

For more information about the MSVC and MinGW flavors of the Rust toolchains, you can check out [the official documentation](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/installation/windows.html).

Update: version 0.3.0 of the `cloudflare-zlib-sys` crate fixes Windows MinGW builds, so this workaround is no longer needed if you're using the latest version of that crate.